# Search always returns every record in the table

Tags: sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I created a simple full text search rails app using the sunspot_rails and sunspot_solr gems.  The search always returns every record from the database regardless of the search term.

```rb
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @foos = Foo.search do
      fulltext params[:query]
    end.result

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => "index" }
      format.xml { render :xml => @foos }
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  searchable do
    text :name
  end

end
```

```rb
  resources :foos do
    collection do
      get :search
    end
  end
```

```rb
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'sunspot_rails','~> 2.5.0'
gem 'sunspot_solr','~> 2.5.0'
```

I run `bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex` before going to the index page, type any search term and the controller returns every record in the foos table regardless of the search term I give it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the [docs](http://outoftime.github.io/sunspot/docs/) and couldn't find a `.result` method but there is a `.results` which the docs say return an array with the first 30 results by default.  Maybe this is your issue?

Comment: Thank you for helping!  Yes, it's weird, when I use `.results` I get ````undefined method 'results' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00007face5b86ae8> Did you mean? result````  Maybe a gem or config issue?

Comment: [Ransack](https://rubygems.org/gems/ransack) is a different gem.  You must have a name collision.  If you have ransack in your gem file try uninstalling it.